# Template throwing - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'match' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, templates

I have the following template in my html

```
<script id="mapview-tpl" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<div class='header'><a href='#' class="button header-button header-button-left">Back</a><h1>Map</h1></div>
 <div class='details'>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
            zoom: 8
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
                mapOptions);
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>
<div id="map-canvas"/>


</div>
```

and i have a function to 'transition' the view from a home view to this view using the following

```
route: function() {
        var self = this;
        var hash = window.location.hash;
        if (!hash) {
            if (this.homePage) {
                this.slidePage(this.homePage);
            }else {
                this.homePage = new HomeView(this.store).render();
                this.slidePage(this.homePage);
            }
            return;
        }
        var match = hash.match(this.detailsURL);
        if (match) {
            this.store.findById(Number(match[1]), function(employee) {
                self.slidePage(new EmployeeView(employee).render());
            });
        }

        match = hash.match(this.mapsURL);
        if (match) {

            this.store.findById(Number(match[1]), function(employee) {
                self.slidePage(new MapView(employee).render());
            });
        }
    },
```

and upon reaching the end of the function above, the following error will be thrown
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'match' of undefined` hmm anyone?

======

## Added

I forgot to add that this error only thrown when the (this.mapsURL) is called meaning, it will only throw this error when the

```
match = hash.match(this.mapsURL);
    if (match) {

        this.store.findById(Number(match[1]), function(employee) {
            self.slidePage(new MapView(employee).render());
        });
    }
```

is called. The If above it works just fine

Comment: `hash` is probably undefined. And there is no function `match` of `undefined`. Add a `hash = hash === undefined ? "" : hash`

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of scenarios I usually use `test` which is safer in case of `undefined` values: `(this.detailsURL).test(hash)` and `(this.mapsURL).test(hash)`.

In your case I would anyway also check for the `hash` value to understand what is going on: it should be "" in case of no hash but it's not even `undefined` - otherwise it should enter your first condition and return I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me!!! found out that this could be a 'generic' error from a template that couldn't be compiled and in my case, the template name was wrongly defined! Thanks